# Nest Js new HttpService Per Request

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

I have the following global HTTP module

```
import { Global, HttpModule, Module, HttpService } from '@nestjs/common';

@Global()
@Module({
    imports: [HttpModule.register({
        timeout: 7000,
    })],
    exports: [HttpModule],
    providers: []
})
export class HttpGlobalModule {

}
```

which is an HTTP module that injects HTTP services for other modules and i would like to do the following :

I would like this module to provide a new HTTP service per request?

problems that I am facing: 
When I try to add HTTP service in providers array , I am receiving the following error:

```
 Nest can't resolve dependencies of the HttpService (?). Please make sure that the argument AXIOS_INSTANCE_TOKEN at index [0] is available in the HttpGlobalModule context.

Potential solutions:
- If AXIOS_INSTANCE_TOKEN is a provider, is it part of the current HttpGlobalModule?
- If AXIOS_INSTANCE_TOKEN is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within HttpGlobalModule?
```

any help would be deeply appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I'm actually curious why you need a new instance of an Http Service per request? Normally this is considered an anti-pattern as it creates a lot of overhead in your service and if the instances are not cleaned up, that can lead to a big memory leak. That being said I do think this is a solvable problem I'm just curious if this is a band-aid for something you're trying to accomplish? I'm happy to help if I can :)

Comment: Hello thanks for you comment, actually I am trying to prevent another issue in my application I am using Axios interceptor to modify the headers of all outbound request and log those request, to use Axios interceptor you have to use Axios ref for the HTTP instance, so what is happening is when I deploy to lambda Axios interceptor manager is keep pushing new handlers into the request handlers array and that is causing my application to fail in the second request and to return 500 so I think this is related to the idea that serverless is using the same instance thus freezing it

Comment: .Note: this don't happen locally

Comment: Also my i am using the interceptor inside a middleware for all routes /do you have any idea on how to avoid this, I really need help with that

Comment: Do you have this code on Github or somewhere where I can take a look? I have some thoughts but I need more context about how your project is set up.

Comment: Hello Brother 
I can share the screen with you to review the code over zoom or something like that but the code is private for a company

Comment: @Ala'aMezian  did you ever an answer to this problem?